# ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms - global error handling troubles

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-4.0, webforms

I'm back in ASP.NET land after a longer Winforms hiatus - and I'm back at struggling with stuff that is *supposed* to work - but really isn't....

I'm trying to implement a global ASP.NET error handler and a page to show the error to the developer (in a DEV environment).

In `global.asax.cs`, I catch unhandled errors like this:

```
private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

    if (ex != null) 
    {
       HttpContext.Current.Items["exception"] = ex;

       // do a bit more stuff here, like logging the error and so on 

       Server.Transfer("~/Error.aspx");
    }
}
```

(*PS: as a side-note: is using `Server.GetLastError()` or `HttpContext.Current.Error` the preferred way to go? Cannot really find any hard facts on what's better to use, and why*)

and in my "dev" error page, I'm trying to show the error on screen - but trying to get that error seems elusive - I only ever get back `null`...

```
public partial class Error : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // both "exc" as well as "exc2" always end up being "null" ...
        Exception exc = HttpContext.Current.Error;
        Exception exc2 = HttpContext.Current.Items["exception"] as Exception;

        // display error .....
    }
```

**Why**? I was assuming that if I use `Server.Transfer()` that error would still be there (I'm never calling `Server.ClearError()`), and if that doesn't work, then I would expect that at least sticking the exception into `HttpContext.Items` would work since that's still code running inside the same HTTP context/request - no?

What am I missing here? And how *can I* "transport" exception information from catching it in `global.asax.cs` to a separate error page otherwise?

Thanks for all hints and pointers !

---

**Update:** OK - seems this doesn't happen always - in some cases, this mechanism works just fine (as I had expected it to work).

**BUT:** I have a grid on a page that contains `ImageButton` for actions like edit and delete. I have defined a `MyGridViewHandleRowCommand` event handler to handle those commands - but that doesn't seem to work. Whenever I click on one of those image buttons, my error page gets activated - and yes, the code seems to **totally bypass** my global `Application_Error` handler in `global.asax`! And in this case, I cannot get any information about the error in the error page - everything is null .....

Comment: Side note, have you considered using Elmah? http://nuget.org/packages/elmah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solved:

The problem was the fact that something went wrong during an Ajax call, and the async error handling doesn't work as the "normal" error handling through `Application_OnError` but has its own "path" to get to the error page. That's why my error page was hit, but there was no error to be found.

Other than that, the global error handling (for non-Ajax calls) works as expected and as coded.

Answer (score 0):

I guess as you are setting the excption to `Items` property, maybe I can use the `Server.ClearError()` before transfer the page.

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I put the exception in a Session and used a redirect to the error page.